# Is there a way to define a default value inside the function?

Tags: python, function

The title says it already, is it possible to define a value mentioned as default value in the function itself, I tried something like this, but this raises a NameError:

```
def func(x = y):
    y = 6
    print(x)

func(1)
func()
```

Comment: This is only valid if `y` has a value within the scope where `func` is defined.  If you want the default to be 6, just do `def func(x = 6):`.

Comment: We need you to be clear about what semantics you expect.  How does it differ from the straightforward default value (which you've already learned or looked up before you considered posting this question)?

Comment: Yes you can specify a default argument for a function input using the method in your example.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem. No, you can't do that, but if you say why exactly you want that, what it is that you are trying to accomplish, you might get a more useful answer.

Comment: @zvone for reference: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)

Comment: @imLightSpeed No, it fails with an error: `NameError: name 'y' is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your declaration of `y = 6` *inside* the function makes it a local variable. It is not in scope to be used as a default parameter.

Generally, you specify an actual value for the default parameter, like this:

```
def func(x=6):
    print(x)

func(1)
func()
```

If you *really* want to use a variable, then declare that somewhere *before* the function so its in scope when the function is declared, like this:

```
y = 6

def func(x=y):
    print(x)

func(1)
func()
```

The first example is preferred, but there are some valid use cases for the second approach of using a variable as the default.

For instance, you may be retrieving default values from a configuration file elsewhere and want to use them in your program. In Python, there is the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module for this purpose. You could use it like this:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

def func(x=config['defaults']['x']):
    print(x)

func(1)
func()
```

where your `config.ini` file looks like this:

```
[defaults]
x = 6
```

Comment: This `def func(x=y)` is valid syntax, but it is usually worse than the simpler `def func(x=6)`. OP might expect the default to change when `y` is modified, which is not going to happen. And even if not, this just makes the code less readable.

Comment: @zvone thanks, its a valid point, I provided the 2nd example to demonstrate that its possible to use a variable as a default. I've updated my explanation with some more context on where this could be appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign it to a variable, you have to directly write the value in the parenthesis:

```
def func(x=6):
    print(x)

func(1)
func()
```

Comment: "*You can't assign it to a variable*" - technically, this isn't actually correct, You *can* assign it to a variable as long as its in scope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for something like this:

```
def func(x = 6):
    print(x)

func(1)
func()
```

which outputs:

```
1
6
```